# Why does this loop not work?

Tags: c++, for-loop

It's a very simple program. I have a function defined on the top and in the loop I am calling the function `print`.

But I am getting the following errors:

```
prog.cpp:5: error: variable or field ‘print’ declared void
prog.cpp:5: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:11: error: ‘print’ was not declared in this scope
```

Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

void print( a ) {
    cout << a << endl;
}

int main() {
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) print( i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Type of "a" in the function parameter?

Comment: [This good set of c++ tutorials](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) may help you.

Comment: why so many downvotes? The OP provide a minimal working example and the error message is complete.

Comment: @Gigi I'm reading it right now and it's really good. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to declare the type of `a` when defining `print`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
void print( int a ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn have dynamic types. So you need to specify type of "a" variable manually or use function template.

```
void print( int a ) {
    cout << a << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print( T a ) {
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
void print( int a ) { // notice the int
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print( int a ) {
    cout << a << endl;
}

int main() {
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) print( i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```